# Pass .Subject and .Body Outlook properties using VBA

Tags: vba

I have to develop VB macros to create record in Oracle database from e-mail. I successfully create one. It currently connect to database, and create record in database from predefined fields in macros. I have left to develop 1 thing.

My script shall grep email subject and body from .Subject and .Body outlook properties and insert it into "p_descr" db column.

```
Sub MainFlow()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim dbconnstring As String
    Dim plsql As String
    plsql = ""


    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={ORA_VER};DBQ=HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD"
    cn.Open

    MsgBox (cn.Version)

      plsql = plsql & "declare "
      plsql = plsql & "  result tms.api.msg; "
      plsql = plsql & "begin "
      plsql = plsql & "     dbms_output.enable; "
      plsql = plsql & "     result := tms.api.addtask_m(p_userid => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_activity => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_client => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_environment => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_product => 'XXXX', " 'correct Prod
      plsql = plsql & "     p_descr => 'XXXX', " 'very dangerous description, quotation marks - for example
      plsql = plsql & "     p_class => 'XXXX', " 'class task
      plsql = plsql & "     p_empl => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_owner => 'XXXX', "
      plsql = plsql & "     p_duedate => '07-OCT-2019'); " 'due date func
      plsql = plsql & "     dbms_output.put_line(result.txt); "
      plsql = plsql & "     dbms_output.get_line(:line, :status);"
      plsql = plsql & "end;"

        Set cm = New ADODB.Command
        With cm
         .ActiveConnection = cn
         .CommandText = plsql
         .CommandType = adCmdText
         .Prepared = True
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("line", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 32000)
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("status", adInteger, adParamOutput, 32000)
         .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

         MsgBox (cm.Parameters("line").Value)
    End With


    cn.Close


    'get current mail item
    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
    MsgBox (objItem.Subject)
    'MsgBox (objItem.Body)


    End Sub



    Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
        Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

        Set objApp = Application
        On Error Resume Next
        Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
            Case "Explorer"
                Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
            Case "Inspector"
                Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        End Select

        Set objApp = Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: VBScript or VB.NET or VBA Macros? You've managed to mention all 3 in the question, but it's unclear which environment you're actually writing this code in. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, you haven't asked us a question, described a problem, or mentioned an error. Merely having a requirement to code something new isn't a problem or question. We're not really here to do all your work for you, unless it's very trivial. We will _help_ you with your problem, but not just go away and do all the thinking.  What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck, _exactly_?

Comment: Sorry for not defining that. I'm using VBA macros. Actually what I need to do is to insert email subject and body into specific datafield (p_descr). I have tried a lot different ways to do this and every time failed. I tried to do the next: plsql = plsql & "     p_descr => 'objItem.Subject', " but the script only insert objItem.Subject string in database but not the actual e-mail subject as I excpected.

Comment: "I'm using VBA macros"...then please set an appropriate blue tag for your question. VB.NET is something quite different.